# Active record query relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have models called `project`, `gold_task` and `submissions`.

Relationship goes like this:

`project has_many gold_tasks`

`gold_tasks has_many submissions`

How can i get all the submissions of a gold_task through project id.

I tried in the below way

`p.gold_tasks.joins(:submissions)`

Here i'm getting all gold_tasks but i need all submissions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `p.gold_tasks.submissions` should return an array of submissions in this case. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is your question right here "How can i get all the submissions of a gold_task through project id?"

If you have set up your Rails associations correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
@project = Project.find(1)
@gold_tasks = @project.gold_tasks
```

Rails automatically will look up all the rows in the gold_tasks table for all rows with a Project id of 1 and return an array of what it finds. Furthermore, building objects is easy as well. Let's assume we have a project row again:

```
@project = Project.find(1)
@gold_task = @project.gold_task.build(hash)
```

This will build a new gold_task with a parameter hash and assign the @project id to it.

Check out this guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`p.gold_tasks.submissions`